# Why is there multiple period in file names?

Tags: javascript

This is a really basic question ig, but why do people name their files with multiple periods in them, i.e., "blogs.models.js"

Answer (score 1):

Because is not recommended to have white spaces in file names, some people also use "-" or "_" to separate the words of the file name.

https://developers.google.com/style/filenames

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/Dealing_with_files

Answer (score 0):

Primarily, and generally: To make it clear what type of data is in the file.

(Sometimes a tool might use the format of the filename for other purposes, e.g. a build tool might look for all the `*.models.js` files to collect all the models together without them having to be specified explicitly in an index file).

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think its any different than using “-” or “_”.
You can categorise files of same type but with different format neatly.

Generally you’ll see files like
*.config.js
*.controller.js